# How to add Google Maps on Sharepoint 2013 using apikey stored in Sharepoint List

Tags: c#, google-maps, variables, sharepoint, ascx

I'm trying to add a Google Maps webpart at a Sharepoint 2013 site. I have an Mapas.ascx file and a Mapas.ascx.cs file.

On my Mapas.ascx I have this:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mapas.ascx.cs" Inherits="Ntasys.SharePoint.Mapas" %>

<iframe id="mapa" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:MYPLACE&key="MYKEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And on my Mapas.ascx.cs I have this:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;


namespace Ntasys.SharePoint
{
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public partial class Mapas : WebPart
{
    public static string apiKey;


   [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    public Mapas()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            obtenerCamposGoogle();
        }
    }

    private void obtenerCamposGoogle()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["XXX"];
                if (list != null)
                {
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = "<where><Eq><FiledRef Name 'Title'/><Value Type = 'Text'>google_apikey</Value></Eq></Where>";
                    SPListItemCollection collitem = list.GetItems(query);

                    foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collitem)
                    {
                        apiKey = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["Valor"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

At the "obtenerCamposGoogle method, I try to get the apikey stored on my sharepoint list called XXX. Then, I want to load that apikey at the  object declared at Mapas.ascx, because it needs an apikey and it is stored only on the sharepoint list. But I don't know how to do that.

Can anyone help me or give me an idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

front-end tag:

```
<iframe width="600"
                height="450"
                frameborder="0" style="border: 0"
                src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<%=apikey %>&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Backend attribute:

```
protected string apikey = string.Empty;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            apikey = "your dynamic key";
        }
```